# Taking JOINed data and making it a row instead of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query that uses a join to pull some information.

```
        SELECT ca.item_id
            ,ca.FIELD_ID
            ,ca.attr_val
            ,ca.upd_dtt
            ,ca.upd_usr
            ,mf.[ITEM_NAME]
        FROM contract_attr ca
        left JOIN mfr mf on ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
```

[image]

The Joined data is coming in as another column for the row. I want this column to be another row:

12, 0, PAR PHARMA, current_timestamp, ''

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean you want the column to be another column? That's what joins do--can you provide some sample data and current and expected output?

Comment: Based on your edit, you want a UNION instead of a JOIN which is not bound / related. The placement will be at the bottom of the first data set (which is really un-ordered)

Comment: @scsimon My apologies, I edited the question. I want the column (PAR PHARMA) to be another row. After row 36 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you require Union all to get those records as rows:

```
    SELECT ca.item_id
        ,ca.FIELD_ID
        ,ca.attr_val
        ,ca.upd_dtt
        ,ca.upd_usr
    FROM contract_attr ca
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ... cols along with, --If no columns available in mfr then provide nulls accordingly before providing column name Item_Name
      ,mf.[ITEM_NAME]
    FROM mfr mf
```

Both columns list has to be identical order

With JOIN to finish question:

```
  SELECT ca.item_id
        ,ca.FIELD_ID
        ,ca.attr_val
        ,ca.upd_dtt
        ,ca.upd_usr
    FROM contract_attr ca
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ca.item_id,9999,mf.[ITEM_NAME],'',''
 FROM mfr mf
 JOIN contract_attr ca on ca.attr_val = mf.[ITEM_PK]
 Order by ca.item_id
```

Comment: That makes sense. But how to I set the 1st column to the correct item_id? If you look at the image above I want the row to have its 1st column be 12(in this case)

Comment: Provide equal number of columns list as in first query if no columns available then you might require to provide null...    Example: NULL as Field_id

Comment: But notice how the 1st column on the 1st row is 12 and the last is PAR PHARMA. How can I make sure the 1st column in the rows made by the 2nd half of the union say the correct number?